# how to "break" in parts a method that takes too much time to finish the process?

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous

I am working in a method (using spring) that will manage a lot of data and information, consulting to the database and generate some files.

I am trying to avoid a `timeout exception`, so, I decided I should use the `@Async` annotation.

Not quite sure if it works as I think or not, but I also realized that I will need the method who calls Async to wait until it is finished...so, could be the same problem, couldn't it?

Is there any way I can have a sort of listener that will read the Async information that is being processed at my bean without have to wait for all the Async process to finish??

Right now is somehow like this

```
private Long myFIrstMethod(){

// DO A LOT OF THINGS AND CALL TO MY ASYNC METHOD
// evaluate if the Async method will have something or not... and based on it make the return
if (myOtherMethod()){
    return soemvalue;
}else{
    return someOtherValue
}

@Async Future<Boolean> myOtherMethod() {
        //do something
         new AsyncResult<Boolean>(true); //or false...
    }

}
```

So, I was thinking, I might get a timeout exception on `myFirstMethod` is there any way to handle long time processing methods and avoiding this exception?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `Timeout`

http://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/io/TimeOut.java

Set your timeout length to the length you want to wait. In the meantime, should your method return in a timely manner, you can cancel the TimeOut.

```
package tjacobs.io;

public class TimeOut implements Runnable {
    private long mWaitTime;
    private boolean mRunning = true;
    private Thread mMyThread;
    private TimeOutCmd mTimeOutCmd;

    public static final int DEFAULT_URL_WAIT_TIME = 30 * 1000; // 30 Seconds
    public static final int NO_TIMEOUT = -1;
    public static final int DEFAULT_WAIT_TIME = NO_TIMEOUT;

    public static interface TimeOutCmd {
        public void timeOut();
    }

    public TimeOut(TimeOutCmd cmd) {
        this(cmd, DEFAULT_WAIT_TIME);
    }
    public TimeOut(TimeOutCmd cmd, int timeToWait) {
        mWaitTime = timeToWait;
        mTimeOutCmd = cmd;
    }

    public void stop() {
        mRunning = false;
        mTimeOutCmd.timeOut();
        if (mMyThread != null) mMyThread.interrupt();
    }

    /**
     * reset the TimeOut
     *
     */
    public void tick() {
        if (mMyThread != null)
            mMyThread.interrupt();
    }

    public void run () {
        mMyThread = Thread.currentThread();
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(mWaitTime);
                stop();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                if (!mRunning) {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```